# npm start command giving error in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, web-development-server, npm-start

i used npx create-react-app basic and the react app was created. I then went into the basic folder and tried `npm start` but it gave me the following error:

> ```
> npm start
>
> basic@0.1.0 start C:\Users\91982\Desktop\html&css\React\basic
> react-scripts start
>
> 'css\React\basic\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
>   throw err;
>   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\91982\Desktop\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
>     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
>   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   requireStack: []
> }
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! basic@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the basic@0.1.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\91982\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-10T19_54_37_385Z-debug.log
> ```

I even tried creating the app with npm but it gave me the same error. The `start` script is present in the json file. npm is updated to the latest version.

Comment: First delete the node modules folder and then again install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

Goto > Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advance system setting\Enviroment variable and set system variables path C:\Windows\System32\ variable and restart your System.

after restarting it will work 100%..

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

- cd to your project directory (Make sure there is a package.json file)
- delete node_modules directory
- npm install && npm start

Answer (score 2):

1. npm install create-react-app -g
2. cd you project folder
3. delete node_modules folder
4. npm install && npm start

Answer (score 0):

It appears you didn't install the dependencies. Run `npm i` or `npm install` to install the dependencies. It's not finding the react-scripts module because it wasn't installed.

Comment: Even though it said it installed the react-scripts module i installed it again anyway yet I got the same error. Can you please specify which dependancies do I need to install

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an issue with your Windows PATH environment variable. It is trying to execute something in the local project node_modules directory, but windows cant find it because it is not in the path.

You can try using the `npx` command instead of `npm`.

```
npx start
```

Npx checks the PATH and local project binaries for executable.

Comment: If you have npm version 5.2.0 and above npx should have been installed with it. You can also install it manually with `npm install -g npx`.

Another option is to add your projects node_modules bin to your PATH. Mine looks like this:
`C:\DSmith\vscode\projects\my-app\node_modules\.bin`

Comment: Same error even after adding the \.bin to path. I also tried adding react-scripts to path but it didn't work. npm and node are the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I had to add C:/Windows/Systen32 to my system variables Path. It started working after that.